# yumによるopen-sslインストール失敗

Tags: centos, yum

`yum install openssl-devel`が失敗します。

```
エラー: パッケージ: krb5-devel-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64 (base)
             要求: krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-18.el7
            インストール: krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
                krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
            利用可能: krb5-libs-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64 (base)
                krb5-libs(x86-64) = 1.15.1-18.el7
エラー: パッケージ: krb5-devel-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64 (base)
             要求: libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-18.el7
            インストール: libkadm5-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64 (@updates)
                libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-19.el7
            利用可能: libkadm5-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64 (base)
                libkadm5(x86-64) = 1.15.1-18.el7
```

インストール済：krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64
要求しているのが：krb5-devel-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64
だから怒られているのでしょうか？
エラーについて解説と、対処法を教えて頂きたいです。
どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

今回インストールしようとしている`openssl-devel`パッケージは`base`リポジトリにしか存在しませんが、依存関係にある`krb5-libs`と`libkadm5`パッケージは`updates`リポジトリでより新しいバージョンが配布されており、システムにもこちらが既にインストールされているため、「`openssl-devel`の要求バージョンと合わない」とエラーになっているように見えます。

http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/Packages/

> krb5-libs-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
>   libkadm5-1.15.1-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
>   openssl-devel-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64.rpm

http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/7/updates/x86_64/Packages/

> krb5-libs-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
>   libkadm5-1.15.1-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
>   openssl-devel (none)

一つの方法として、問題となっているパッケージをいったんダウングレードしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

---

**手順**
パッケージがダウングレード可能か調べる(インストール可能なパッケージバージョンを確認)

```
$ yum --showduplicate list <PACKAGE>
```

バージョン番号を指定してダウングレード

```
$ yum downgrade <PACKAGE>-<VERSION>
```

質問の環境(CentOS7)だと実際の指定は以下の様になると思います。

```
$ yum downgrade krb5-libs-1.15.1-18
$ yum downgrade libkadm5-1.15.1-18
```

なお、必要なパッケージ(`openssl-devel`)が正常にインストール出来たら、`yum update`で再度アップデートしておくことをお薦めします。

参考：
[yumでアップデートした内容を戻す方法 | CloudAdvisor](https://hacknote.jp/archives/5946/)

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。教えて頂いたコマンドを実行しましたが、840 packages excluded due to repository priority protectionsと出て、インストールできませんでした。多くの依存関係があるためダウングレードできないということでしょうか...

Answer (score 2):

質問者ですが
yum erase yum-plugin-priorities
を行い再度インストールを試みるとインストールを行うことができました。
ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

updates リポジトリが無効になっているのではないでしょうか。
`--enablerepo=updates` オプションを付けるとどうなりますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。840 packages excluded due to repository priority protectionsと出てインストールできませんでした。これは困りました...